# How to pass value in MPChart in float and string respectively

Tags: android, android-studio

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
float rainfall[]={1.2f,2.1f,2.3f,3.1f,3.4f,3.5f,4.5f,6.7f};
String month[]={"jan","feb","march","april","may","june","july","aug"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   setupPieChart();

}

private void setupPieChart()
{
    List<PieEntry> pieEntries=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<rainfall.length;i++)
    {
        pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(rainfall[i],month[i]));
    }
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries,"Rain for Vanometer");
   dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    PieData data=new PieData(dataSet);
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText("Rain Scale per Month");
    PieChart chart=(PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    chart.setDescription(description);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.invalidate();
}
```

}

where rainfall is in float and month is in the string but this is working fine for Pie Chart but here is a problem for the Bar Chart. Kindly help me out.

Comment: can you share more code to see your full implementation

Comment: I just added  pls check.

Comment: @RashidNoor post UI sample what you actually want to achieve .